# Javascript chess board

Tags: javascript, chessboard.js

I've been trying to solve the eloquent javascript chessboard exercise with the following code. The lines print in the correct order however for some reason that I cannot seem to find, the loop is infinite. Any help to pointing out what the problem is would be much appreciated, thank you.

my code looks like this:

```
 var line= ['# # # #', ' # # # #']

 for (var i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
    if ( i = (i-1)%2 == 0 )
       console.log(line[0]);
       else console.log(line[1]);
 };
```

Comment: because `i = (i-1)%2 == 0` overrides the value of `i`

Answer (score 1):

`i` will be always lesser than the limit of your loop, because of your assignment inside the `if` condition

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
     // i & 1 is a mask that matches the rightmost bit, which, if set
     // indicates that a number is odd
     console.log(line[i & 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering, I didn't realize the problem with the condition set to i in the if statement (newbie mistakes).
I modified the code to the following one and it works perfectly fine, and it seems to be a way shorter code than the ones offered in other solutions:

```
var line= ['# # # #', ' # # # #']

   for (var i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {

   if ( i%2 == 0 )
      console.log(line[0]);

     else console.log(line[1]);
    };
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatic compute character instead of having an array of values.

```js
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
    html += (i+j) % 2 == 0?"# ":"&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  }
  html+="<br/>"
}
document.write(html)
```